# anonymous function paste function in R

Tags: r

I was wondering how I can replace this for loop with an anonymous function:

```
for(i in 1:length(colnames(data))){ print (paste(colnames (data)[i],data[1,i])) }
```

I was thinking of :

```
lapply(data,function(x) paste(colnames(data)[x],data[1,x] ))
```

But this is giving me error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, 1, x) : undefined columns selected
```

Have also tried

```
lapply(data,function(x) paste(colnames(data)[x], data[1,]))
```

But this pasted down the entire column.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Possibly `paste(names(data), sapply(data, function(x) x[1]))`? Or even `paste(names(data), sapply(data, head, 1))`.

Comment: `paste(colnames(data), unlist(data[1,]))` maybe?

Comment: To closely reproduce the `for` loop, you should use the same index as the first arg of `lapply`, namely `1:length(colnames(data))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're applying to the wrong thing. In the loop you are looping over the numbers from 1 to something.

This works, all I've changed is the first argument:

```
lapply(1:length(colnames(data)), function(x) paste(colnames(data)[x],data[1,x] ))
```

But also, you probably want sapply.

```
sapply(1:length(colnames(data)), function(x) paste(colnames(data)[x],data[1,x] ))
```

Comment: Also, there's nothing wrong with using a for loop! The solution you have is fine

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me like you could ditch the looping and do the following instead.

```
paste(colnames(data), unlist(data[1, ]))
```

And if you want it stacked similar to the output from using `print()` in your `for()` loop, you could wrap it with `rbind()`.

Comment: I like this, this is nice!